# Приватные методы класса. "Unexpected token '('"

Tags: javascript, node.js, классы

Имею такой метод:

```
    async #initCurrenciesDataFromApi() {
        const getData = await this.network.get(this.#api);
        return getData.data;
    }
```

При запуске получаю:

```
async #initCurrenciesDataFromApi() {
                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
```

Comment: `function` не забыли случаем?

Comment: В классе не нужно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Свойства класса по умолчанию являются общедоступными и могут быть
> рассмотрены или изменены вне класса. Тем не менее, есть
> экспериментальное предложение, позволяющее определить приватные поля
> класса, используя префикс хэша #.

[Приватные поля класса на mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

---

Возможно браузер не поддерживает новые возможности.

Поддержка в node.js, скорее всего, с [15той версии](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--private-class-methods).

Попробуйте запустить рабочий пример:

```js
class Class {
  #api = '123';
  async fun() {
    return this.#initCurrenciesDataFromApi();
  }
  async #initCurrenciesDataFromApi() {
    const getData = await this.network.get(this.#api);
    return getData.data;
  }
  get network() {
    return {
      get(x) {
        console.log(x);
        return Promise.resolve({ data: true });
      }
    };
  }
}

const z = new Class();
z.fun().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Должен показать в консоли

> 123
>
> true

Проверено на *Node.js v14.13.0*

```
xxx:~ $ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.13.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> class Class {
...   #api = '123';
...   async fun() {
.....     return this.#initCurrenciesDataFromApi();
.....   }
...   async #initCurrenciesDataFromApi() {
.....     const getData = await this.network.get(this.#api);
.....     return getData.data;
.....   }
...   get network() {
.....     return {
.......       get(x) {
.........         console.log(x);
.........         return Promise.resolve({ data: true });
.........       }
.......     };
.....   }
... }
undefined
> 
> const z = new Class();
undefined
> z.fun().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
123
Promise { <pending> }
> true
```

Comment: У меня nodejs. 14.4.0

Comment: @Lasna1 хорошо. тестовый пример запускается nodejs? отрабатывает? если ответ - да, то проблема не в тех четырёх строках кода, которые вы показали

Comment: Нет, не работает. Спасибо Вам. Сейчас 15-ую скачаю, гляну.

Comment: @Lasna1 у меня запускается на Node.js v14.13.0. приложил листинг

Comment: @Lasna1 судя по https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--private-class-methods в nodejs вашей версии может и не работать

Comment: Скачал последнюю (15-ую) - работает.

Comment: @Lasna1 Добавил эту информацию в ответ