# Как писать unit тесты для защищенных методов?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты

Имею класс с защищенными методами.

Как писать для них тесты?

Можно ли использовать sinon stub для них?

Comment: Никак не писать. Тестируйте публичный интерфейс.. Вопрос точно про javascript?

Comment: К сожалению да. Даже публичный интерфейс требует redis, который, вызывается из защищенного. Stub не поставить?

Comment: redis и всё остальное нужно mock'ать

Comment: А давно в js защищённые методы завезли?

Comment: @vp_arth завезли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1193766/2659

Comment: Это же приватные?

Comment: @vp_arth  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Приватные  - "_private", но он как бы позволяет обратится к ниму и т.д, фактически это именное соглашение. А вот это "#protected".

Comment: P.S а смогу ли я заглушку/mock поставить на приватный метод? Либо вообще переписать их, без "защищенности"?